# BLE beacon for indoor navigation

Tags: android, beacon, indoor-positioning-system

I want develop a mobile app (for Android) for indoor navigation on my university. Which a programming language is the best for that? Can I use for example JavaScript for frontend and PHP for backend?

Thanks :)

Comment: What would you use the backend for? As the question is formulated, it's impossible to say why any backend language would be better than any other in this case. And for frontend - remember that the "native" language on Android is Java. You can of course try other solutions but then you need extra libraries and tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I work for an indoor navigation company.

There is no programming language that is *"better"* for indoor navigation. If you are comfortable with javascript, I would say use that rather than learning a new language altogether. I say that because developing an "indoor navigation" application can be a pretty big undertaking without any third party platforms that do a lot of the heavy lifting for you (Map Rendering, Map Management, Wayfinding Logic, etc). There is also a lot of new terminology that you may need to learn in order to even begin searching for the right answers.

A few things you may want to look into are:

**Map Digitizing,** You'll need find an up to date map somehow. This is a lot harder than it sounds. Further, once you find it you'll need to convert it into a format that is both lightweight & accurate. PNG, SVG, GeoJSON, KML, WKT are some formats to look at. GeoJSON might be your best bet.

**Map Rendering,** There are a lot of great open source rendering engines you can use that have great documentation. There are also a lot of paid & enterprise ones.

**Wayfinding,** This is drawing a path from one point, typically the users location, to another, the end destination. Here is an example of how some wayfinding algorithms work: https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/

**Map Management,** Indoor spaces change much more frequently than outdoor. Think about your example, a University will have different classes & schedules each semester- this will need to be managed in a CMS somehow and by someone.

That isn't everything, but should be enough to get you started.